# ggplot2: Is there a way to overlay a single plot to all facets in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot and faceting to construct a series of density plots grouped by a factor. Additionally, I would like to a layer another density plot on each of the facets that is not subject to the constraints imposed by the facet.

For example, the faceted plot would look like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + facet_grid(.~clarity) + geom_density()
```

and then I would like to have the following single density plot layered on top of each of the facets:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + geom_density()
```

Furthermore, is ggplot with faceting the best way to do this, or is there a preferred method?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to make new data frame `diamonds2` that contains just column `price` and then two `geom_density()` calls - one which will use original `diamonds` and second that uses `diamonds2`. As in `diamonds2` there will be no column `clarity` all values will be used in all facets.

```
diamonds2<-diamonds["price"]
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + geom_density()+facet_grid(.~clarity) + 
     geom_density(data=diamonds2,aes(price),colour="blue")
```

[image]

**UPDATE** - as suggested by @BrianDiggs the same result can be achieved without making new data frame but transforming it inside the `geom_density()`.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + geom_density()+facet_grid(.~clarity) +
     geom_density(data=transform(diamonds, clarity=NULL),aes(price),colour="blue")
```

Another approach would be to plot data without faceting. Add two calls to `geom_density()` - in one add `aes(color=clarity)` to have density lines in different colors for each level of `clarity` and leave empty second `geom_density()` - that will add overall black density line.

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(price))+geom_density(aes(color=clarity))+geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. If I had enough reputation, I would upvote :) Cheers.

Comment: A slight variation on the first approach: you don't have to make a named `diamonds2` ahead of time. You can declare it in-line in the data argument to the second `geom_density()`: `data=transform(diamonds, clarity=NULL)`

Comment: @BrianDiggs Thanks. I also had similar idea after posted answer but decided to leave this way to show that other data don't have this column and to be more general (if there is already other data frame available).